# istio routes issue for application path

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, istio

Im using `istio` latest version `1.17` and my application is having 
few routes

for example

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name:virtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - ingressgateway
  http:
  - match:
      - uri:
          prefix: "/"
      - uri:
          exact: "/api/users"
    route:
      - destination:
          host: stb-mvs-us
```

now when use ingress gateway

`kubectl get svc -n istio-system -l istio=ingressgateway`

I see the external ip and if I use it like:

http://6026651-81434690.eu-central-1.elb.fds.com

I see the index page and **it works**

but my application is exposing also routes like

"/api/users”

When I access it via browser I got error 503, what could be the reason?

http://6026651-81434690.eu-central-1.elb.fds.com/api/users

If I switch service (for testing) to using LoadBalancer I can see that the route "/api/users” is working…
Does my `virtual service` config is wrong?

**update**

as suggested I've changed it to the following

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name:virtualservice
spec:
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - ingressgateway
  http:
  - match:
      - uri:
          exact: "/api/users"
    route:
      - destination:
          host: stb-mvs-us
```

and I was able to see the root (index.html) and not able to see the path `api/users` e.g. http://6026651-81434690.eu-central-1.elb.fds.com/api/users

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: http-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "*"
```

Comment: Have you tried to exclude `prefix: "/"` match criteria from the origin configuration with only one `"/api/users"` existing and check behavior?

Comment: @mk_sta - thanks for your replay. I've changed as (please see my update) and still not working for the path `api/users` , did I miss somehting ?

Comment: @mk_sta - what is strange is that if I use wrong path like `api/aaaa` I still the the index page and not getting error as I expected as this path is not exist in my app...

Comment: Can you share `ingressgateway` Gateway resourse?

Comment: @mk_sta - i've used helm to install the latest version , do you mean results of command `kubectl get svc -n istio-system -l istio=ingressgateway ` ?

Comment: I mean Istio [Gateway](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/gateway/) resource for the particular `VirtualService`.

Comment: @mk_sta - please see my update

Comment: I see that you use different gateway in `VirtualService` specification.

Comment: @mk_sta -sorry I provide the wrong ingressgatay (from diff cluster) I've verified the the virtual service is using the same `http-gateway` and still it doesnt works :(

Comment: Have you injected Istio sidecar into the target Pod?